# PowerShell command for ffmpeg to process items in a folder recursively

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, powershell, recursive

I'm trying to figure out what PowerShell command [or script if necessary] might allow `ffmpeg` to recursively traverse a directory, pull stills via the `-vf` flag, and put all the stills into a folder without any filename conflicts that would cause overwriting.

So I know that this works fine for an individual file:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -vf fps=10/60 still%04d.jpg
```

The files generated start from `still0001.jpg` and count up to `still0002.jpg`, `still0003.jpg`, etc.

I have a directory that looks like this, with video files at different levels:

- `topFolder1`

  - `midFolder1`

    - `video1.mov`
    - `video2.mov`
  - `midFolder2`

    - `video3.mov`
    - `video4.mov`

I'm trying to use a PowerShell command that can pull stills from all the videos `video1.mov`, `video2.mov`, `video3.mov`, and `video4.mov` and drop them into one folder.

I found [a PowerShell command that purports to have ffmpeg traverse a directory recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784661/how-do-you-convert-an-entire-directory-with-ffmpeg/24273691#24273691), but when I try to adapt it, it's not working.

I run:

```
PS T:\Exports\1 - Dailies\stills test> for /F "tokens=*" "%G" IN ('dir "T:\Exports\1 - Dailies" *.mov') do ffmpeg -i "%G" -vf fps=10/60 still%05d.jpg
```

But I get this error:

```
At line:1 char:4
+ for /F "tokens=*" "%G" IN ('dir "T:\Exports\1 - Dailies" *.mov') do f...
+    ~
Missing opening '(' after keyword 'for'.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingOpenParenthesisAfterKeyword
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The command that you are running is intended for cmd.exe or batch file execution. Not powershell. To convert this to powershell research these commands: `Get-ChildItem`, `foreach`, and `Invoke-Expression` among others.

Comment: @EBGreen OK. Running it in `cmd.exe` returns: `"%G" was unexpected at this time.`. Any ideas?

Comment: The link that you provided literally says that you need to double the % symbols. The command in that link is also quoted differently than the command that you are running.

Comment: @user260467 Try to convert your iteration routine logic to run via PS commands, edit your question with what you are trying code wise, to potentially help draw more attention for some assistance as you need. Simply, take a few minutes, and tag me back afterwards. Otherwise run your looped command from `cmd.exe` and not `powershell.exe` and see what happens because at least error `At line:1 char:4` should not occur.

Comment: @EBGreen Yes, this is not a batch `.bat` file. Also, I _am_ trying a different command.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example of a powershell command for converting all files in a directory to mp4 and resizing to 1280x720:

```
dir *.* | foreach-object { $newname = $_.Name.Remove($_.Name.Length - $_.Extension.Length) + ".mp4"; .\ffmpeg.exe -i "$_" -s 1280x720 $newname }
```

Comment: if needed, set your working directory like that `Set-Location -Path "C:\Users\user"`. Also I had to add a line break instead of the `; .\``    in  `".mp4"; .\ffmpeg.exe ` and remove the `.exe`